# Report Builder 3 - Empty chart

Tags: charts, report, builder

I'm SQL Server 2012 SP1, Report builder and SQL Server are installed on a Windows Server 2012 machine.

I have an issue with charts... When I try to build a chart here is what I get as result:

[image]

Nothing, no data, I tried with almost all type of charts, same thing...

I have this issue only with charts, when I use table or matrix it works well, I can see all data.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have done to solve this issue:

1. Restart SSRS service
2. Repair SSRS